# How can I copy all objects from one Amazon S3 bucket to another bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, object, amazon-s3, copy, bucket

I want to copy my folder/object from one s3 bucket to other. How can I possible to copy?

Answer (score 1):

You cam use the `aws s3 sync` cli command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-SOURCE s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-TARGET
```

See the documentation here : [S3 CLI Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)

If you have a large amount of data check here: [What's the best way to transfer large amounts of data from one Amazon S3 bucket to another?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/)